# Change of two normal coordinates based on two nearby points?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, principal-bundles, tangent-bundle

Let $M$ be a manifold and $L(M)$ be the [tangent frame bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Tangent_frame_bundle) on $M$. Let $\Gamma$ be a [linear connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)#Formal_definition) on $L(M)$ which induces a [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Formal_definition) $\nabla$ on $TM$.

Let $p, q$ be two distinguished and sufficiently close points on $M$, connected by a smooth curve $\gamma = \{\gamma_t\}_{t\in[0,\epsilon]}$ so that $\gamma(0)=p$, $\gamma(\epsilon)=q$. Suppose that there is an open set $U\subset M$, such that $U$ contains $\gamma$ and is a [normal neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates#Geodesic_normal_coordinates) of both $p$ and $q$.

Fix a linear frame $u_p \in L_p(M): \mathbf R^d\to T_pM$. Let $u_q = \Gamma(\gamma)_0^\epsilon (u_p) \in L_q(M)$ be the [parallel displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport#Generalizations) of $u_p$ along $\gamma$, that is, $u_q$ can be joined to $u_p$ by a horizontal curve on $L(M)$ along $\gamma$.

Then we have two normal coordinate systems on $U$:
$$x=u_p^{-1}\circ \exp_p^{-1}: U \to \mathbf R^d,$$
$$y=u_q^{-1}\circ \exp_q^{-1}: U \to \mathbf R^d,$$
so that $(U,(x^i))$ and $(U,(y^j))$ are coordinate charts based on $p$ and $q$ respectively.

---

Now my **question** is: how to do change of coordinates between these two normal coordinate charts? More precisely, let $m \in U$, then what is the relation between $x(m)$ and $y(m)$?

If necessary, you can endow more structures to $M$. Say, $M$ is equipped with a Riemannian metric $g$ and $\nabla$ is the [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), the frame bundle $L(M)$ is replaced by the [orthonormal frame bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Orthonormal_frame_bundle) $O(M)$...

---

Some thinking: Clearly, $x(p) = y(q) = 0$. If $\gamma$ is a *geodesic*, then it is easy to check $x(q) = -y(p)$. Denote $\rho = x(q) \in\mathbf R^d$. Then I believe that $x(m) = y(m) + \rho$ for all $m \in U$. If $\gamma$ is *not a geodesic*, then I think that a curvature term should appear, since we may use the [holonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Ambrose%E2%80%93Singer_theorem). But I do not know how to prove my conjectures...

---

**EDIT:** I think there maybe no exact expressions for $x(m)$ and $y(m)$, but there should be an asymptotic expression with infinitesimals $o(\epsilon)$ or $o(d(x,y))$...

Comment: Crosspost on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404460/change-of-two-normal-coordinates-based-on-two-nearby-points).

Comment: Indeed, there's not going to be an explicit description of $x(m)$ and $y(m)$. However, if you extend the definition of $x$ and $y$ to a map $x_t$, for each starting point $\gamma_t$. then you can probably derive equations that $\partial_tx_t$ satisfy. This is because $x_t$ is defined by families of geodesics, and the derivative with respect to the parameters that the geodesics depend on give you Jacobi fields, which satisfy the Jacobi equations. You can then study these equations.

Comment: @Deane Thank you professor Deane, for the nice hint. Yes, it is better to define $x(t) = u_t^{-1}(\exp_{\gamma(t)}^{-1}m)$. Then the problem is translated to find out the derivative $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$. But still, I do not know how to use Jacobi fields to calculate this derivative...

Comment: @Deane I think I know what you mean by making use of Jacobi fields. I am now going to try it. Thank you!

Comment: @Deane Thank you professor. Inspired by your comments, I posted a partial answer to this general question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the instructive comments by @Deane, and by @WillieWong in the crosspost on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404460/change-of-two-normal-coordinates-based-on-two-nearby-points).

---

First of all, the shift property $x(m) = y(m) + \rho$ that I conjectured in my question is not true in general. See the comments by @WillieWong for a counterexample.

---

Secondly, inspired by their comments, I am now trying to give a feasible option instead of a complete solution, as the question is actually quite general.

Denote
\begin{align*}
u_t &= \Gamma(\gamma)_0^t (u_p) \in L_{\gamma(t)}(M), \\
x_t &= u_t^{-1} \circ \exp_{\gamma(t)}^{-1} (m) \in \mathbf R^d, \\
V(t) &= u_t x_t = \exp_{\gamma(t)}^{-1} (m) \in T_{\gamma(t)} M, \\
\gamma_s(t) &=  \exp_{\gamma(t)}(sV(t)) \in M.
\end{align*}
Then for each $t$, $\gamma_\cdot(t)$ is a geodesic satisfying $\gamma_0(t) = \gamma(t)$ and $\gamma_1(t) \equiv m$. This leads to a Jacobi field $J_t$ along $\gamma_\cdot(t)$ for each $t$:
\begin{equation*}
J_t(s) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \gamma_s(t) = \dot\gamma_s(t),
\end{equation*}
which satisfies the Jacobi equation:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{D^2}{ds^2} J_t(s) + R\left( J_t(s), \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \gamma_s(t) \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \gamma_s(t) = 0,
\end{equation}
subjected to two boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
J_t(0) = \dot\gamma_0(t) = \dot\gamma(t),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
J_t(1) = \dot\gamma_1(t) = 0.
\end{equation}
Now the torsion-freeness (which needs to be assumed in the beginning) gives
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\frac{D}{ds} J_t(0) &= \frac{D}{ds} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \gamma_s(t) \bigg|_{s=0} = \frac{D}{dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \gamma_s(t) \bigg|_{s=0} = \frac{D}{dt} V(t) \\
&= \frac{d}{dh}\bigg|_{h=0} u_t\circ u_{t+h}^{-1} (V(t+h)) = \frac{d}{dh}\bigg|_{h=0} u_t x_{t+h} = u_t \dot x_t,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
which gives
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\dot x_t = u_t^{-1} \left( \frac{D}{ds} J_t(0) \right).
\end{equation}
Therefore, in order to obtain $\dot x_t$ which is exactly the purpose of the question, one need first solve the boundary value problem $(1)$-$(3)$ to get $J_t(s)$, and then calculate $\frac{D}{ds} J_t(0)$ and finally use $(4)$ to derive $\dot x_t$.